# Getting error while running script

Tags: php, mysql

Please I get this error code when executting this script
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a777gqka/public_html/testserver/index.php on line 47

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT
e.id,
ts.name AS stage_name,
DATE_FORMAT(e.startdate, '2013-05-15') AS startdate,
DATE_FORMAT(e.startdate, 'H:i') AS starttime,
MIN(if( ep.number = 1, p.name, NULL)) AS home_team,
if(e.status_type = \"notstarted\", \"-\",(MIN(if(ep.number = 1, r.value, NULL))))  AS home_score,
if(e.status_type = \"notstarted\", \"-\",(MIN(if(ep.number = 2, r.value, NULL)))) AS away_score,
MIN(if(ep.number = 2, p.name, NULL)) AS away_team,
es.name AS status_text
FROM
tournament_template AS tt INNER JOIN
tournament AS t ON t.tournament_templateFK = tt.id INNER JOIN
tournament_stage AS ts ON t.id = ts.tournamentFK INNER JOIN
event AS e ON ts.id = e.tournament_stageFK INNER JOIN
event_participants AS ep ON e.id = ep.eventFK LEFT JOIN
status_desc AS es ON e.status_descFK = es.id LEFT JOIN
participant AS p ON ep.participantFK = p.id LEFT JOIN
result AS r ON ep.id = r.event_participantsFK AND r.result_code = \"runningscore\" LEFT JOIN
property AS prop ON e.id = prop.objectFK AND prop.object =\"event\" AND prop.name = \"Live\"
WHERE
tt.sportFK = ".$sportFK."  AND
e.startdate BETWEEN ".$TODAY_FROM." AND ".$TODAY_TO." AND
prop.value = \"yes\"
GROUP BY
e.id
ORDER BY 
ts.id, e.startdate, e.id");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
// Do something
}
```

Comment: How about `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());` ? **NOTE:** PHP's Mysql extension being officially deprecated!

Comment: try to add `or die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());` after `e.startdate, e.id");`

Comment: check your query is it returning some values or not. you can check it by `mysql_num_rows()`. or by echo the query and execute on phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $query = "SELECT .... ";
 if($result = mysql_query($query)){
     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
          //...
     }
 } else {
     echo mysql_error();
 }
```

Besides that you should output your errors, you should at minimum use mysqli. The mysql_* function are deprecated and will be removed with PHP 5.5.

Comment: I got Query was empty as response. Does that mean no match on my database?

Comment: Obviously yes. But you should check with `mysql_num_rows()` as suggested by @Praveen.

Answer (score 0):

you aren't executing the query.

add `$result = mysql_query($query)` before the while loop and change the loop test to `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)`

Also, mysql_* functions are deprecated and will be removed in future updates to PHP. Switch to mysqli_* or PDO.

I personally suggest PDO.

Comment: I did it the way you instructed but here is the response I get    Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a777gqka/public_html/testserver/index.php on line 50

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT...") or die(mysql_error());
if ($query){
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
// Do something
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

please try this

```
if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){

   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
   // Do something
   }
}
else{
    echo "No record found";
}
```

Comment: $query is a string, not a resource. Of course he'll get the same error message.